# Eclipse. Can I delete a Java class constructor such that Eclipse automatically refactors?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an empty constructor for a Class. I want to delete the constructor, but there are many places where I have things such as:

`Klass my_klass = new Klass("");`

I would like to delete the constructor and have Eclipse automatically refactor if it can. The result would look like:

`Klass my_klass = new Klass();`

Eclipse has all sorts of nice refactoring features. Does it have this?

Comment: Why would you want the result generated? The sintax of your result is incorrect, so I doubt that Eclipse will refactor the way you want. Try to explain why you need it and maybe we can help you better.

Comment: 1. Search for `new Klass("")` and replace with `new Klass()`. 2. Remove the constructor `Klass(String s)`.

Comment: @DanielPereira: I don't need it, but if it already exists it would be nice. Oh, fixed the syntax, too per assylias' suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Right click on the constructor you want to remove -> Refactor -> Change method signature.
- Remove the paramaters you want (all of them in your case) and then your Eclipse will change all of your calls to this constructor automatically. If you already have a default constructor it will complain; just press Ok, it will give you a compilation error because you have two constructor with the same parameters,
- Make a merge or delete the old one and you have the result that you want.